JDBC Connection attempt failed in aws Glue notebook while Test Connection succeeds
I can't manage to access postgresql RDS via python notebook in aws glue.
I have setup a security group with all ingress tcp allowed with the source being the security group itself. All outbound is allowed.
I have added the security group to the rds database.
In Aws glue, I have configured a postgresql connection using the same VPC, subnet and security group as rds. Test connection is working fine.
I then start a notebook in the aws glue console and try to connect to the postgresql database using the following code:
url = "jdbc:postgresql://xxxxxx.cpk4quoi6dws.eu-north-1.rds.amazonaws.com:5432/db" 
properties = {
    "user": "xxxxx",  # PostgreSQL username
    "password": "xxxxx",  # PostgreSQL password
    "driver": "org.postgresql.Driver"
}
df = spark.read.jdbc(url=url, table="public.dvfs", properties=properties)

I then get the following error
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o83.jdbc.
: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed.
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:331)
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:49)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:223)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:402)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:261)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.connection.BasicConnectionProvider.getConnection(BasicConnectionProvider.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.connection.ConnectionProviderBase.create(ConnectionProvider.scala:102)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.jdbc.JdbcDialect.$anonfun$createConnectionFactory$1(JdbcDialects.scala:122)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.jdbc.JdbcDialect.$anonfun$createConnectionFactory$1$adapted(JdbcDialects.scala:118)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRDD$.getQueryOutputSchema(JDBCRDD.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRDD$.resolveTable(JDBCRDD.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRelation$.getSchema(JDBCRelation.scala:242)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcRelationProvider.createRelation(JdbcRelationProvider.scala:37)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:350)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:228)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.$anonfun$load$2(DataFrameReader.scala:210)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:210)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:171)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.jdbc(DataFrameReader.scala:248)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:607)
    at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.createSocket(PGStream.java:241)
    at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.<init>(PGStream.java:98)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:109)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:235)
    ... 30 more

What am I doing wrong?

It is necessary to configure the glue job under Job Details > Advanced Properties > Connections for it to use the glue connection.
When using a notebook, this area is greyed out and one must instead use the magic command
%connections "your-connection-name-spaces-are-forbidden"

